# int array to byte array with one integer per byte

Tags: java, arrays

All related questions I've found here on SO describe the conversion between a `byte` array and an `int` array where 4 bytes are converted to a single integer and vice versa.

What I am looking for instead is converting each integer to a single byte and vice versa, knowing that none of the values of the integer array exceeds the range of an unsigned `byte`.

Is there a library that does that (preferably Guava or Apache commons)? Essentially, I am looking for something like this:

`int[]` -> `byte[]`

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
  byteArray[i] = (byte) intArray[i];
}
```

`byte[]` -> `int[]`

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++){
  intArray[i] = 0xff & byteArray[i];
}
```

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk thanks, but the question you linked to describes specifically what I said was not what I wanted. To quote myself: *All related questions I've found here on SO describe the conversion between a byte array and an int array where 4 bytes are converted to a single integer and vice versa.*

Comment: What is wrong with the code snippets you provided?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with them, I was just expecting that a library have an implementation of it. Something like `int[] ArrayUtils.toIntArray(byte[] byteArray)`

Comment: I would not bother looking for a library that does exactly this. Your question is somewhat special. Create a Util class, put your code snippets into two methods, and be happy.

Comment: I was writing more or less what @Absurd-Mind did... It's both such a special and such a simple case, that you are better off doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast arrays in Java in that way. AFAIK, the VM just does not let you reinterpret the bytes in an array as a different type. I assume that you could use some platform-dependent JNI magic to make it so, but that would be extremely hacky.

**Edit** (removed sample code; added following)

If you are going to reinterpret the same bytes as different primitive types, use a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Once declared, you get direct access operations to reinterpreted bytes, such as

```
myByteBuffer.getInt(1);  // reads bytes 4, 5, 6, 7 as an int
myByteBuffer.getByte(5); // reads byte 5 as a byte
```

You can also extract primitive arrays from there, but there will be extra allocations involved.

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for a cast, I am looking for a library that provides an equivalent method to the one you wrote here. Of course I could write my own method (and I did), I was just wondering whether it was implemented in a library already. If not - no harm done :)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
int number  = 54353, divisor = 256;
byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];

byteArray[3] = number%divisor;
number = number/divisor
byteArray[2] = number%divisor;
number = number/divisor
byteArray[1] = number%divisor;
number = number/divisor
byteArray[0] = number;
```

Comment: Not really what was asked.  It can be assumed that the numbers are all within byte range.  The problem deals with array casting.